# Cannot submit form with <select multiple required> in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, validation, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

On first submission, no option in the <select> is selected, causing HTML5 validation to fail, preventing submission altogether.

However, if we then select an option via JavaScript, submission still fails on subsequent submission.

It succeeds if you manually select an option other than the ones already selected (or if you deselect and reselect them).

Bug or feature?
Is it already known behavior or documented somewhere?
I couldn't find any references.

```js
var done = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#s").on("click", function() {
    if (done) {
      return;
    }

    // run once
    done = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#a").prop("selected", true);
      console.log($("#x").val());
    }, 100); // delay to prevent submission with set option
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="get">
  <select id="x" name="x" required="required" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="a" id="a">Anton</option>
    <option value="b">Berta</option>
  </select>

  <input id="s" type="submit" name="btn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I don't understand it correctly I think. When I don't select an option, it fails and when I select one, it submits (which is ok). But when I select one with JS it also submits: https://jsfiddle.net/5hbey7en/2/

Comment: When you manually select an option, everything works. But if you let JavaScript do the selection (and you haven't previously selected any options but already tried to submit and failed because of the "required" attribute), then try to submit, you can't until you manually select an option again. In your fiddle: 1. Don't select anything, only submit to trigger HTML5 error. 2. Click "Select an option". 3. Submit again => error.

Comment: Indeed, now i see that. Thanks for the clarification. I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

It seems it has to do with setting `.prop` on the `<option>`.

When you set the `selectedIndex` on the `select` input, it all works. Check the updated fiddle:

```
document.getElementById('btn-select').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var select = $("#x")[0];

    // select the first one
    // select.selectedIndex = 0;

    // or loop through options and select based on a condition
    for (var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
        if (select.options[i].value === 'b') {
            select.selectedIndex = i;
            return;
        }
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5hbey7en/8/

So your example would become:

```
var done = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#s").on("click", function() {
    if (done) {
      return;
    }

    // run once
    done = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#x")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
      console.log($("#x").val());
    }, 100); // delay to prevent submission with set option
  });
});
```

Comment: This is interesting... I found this issue when I was using bootstrap-multiselect and did not select an option at first and then could not submit afterwards, then reduced it to this basic HTML problem. I could set selectedIndex after the user selects something, but this becomes a dirty workaround because I have to preserve all selections in the multi-select.

Comment: I've fiddled around some more in IE. You always have to set the `selectedIndex` to a value > -1. After that, you can select other options with JS. Check these two fiddles: https://jsfiddle.net/p2pp4Lna/. With 'user selected values`: https://jsfiddle.net/vuymg9r4/3/